# gives error when using get intent in 3rd activity the code is here

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton radioButton1,radioButton2,radioButton3,radioButton4;
Button submit;
TextView tv;
static int score3;
String i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);


    radioGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.groupid);
    radioButton1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    radioButton2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    radioButton3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    radioButton4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio4);
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);


    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(radioButton3.isChecked())
            {

               Intent intent=getIntent();
               String str = intent.getStringExtra("score2");
               score3=Integer.valueOf(str);
               score3++;


            }
            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"wrong answer",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

My error is:

> 09-28 17:53:40.131 1648-1648/com.example.gulmarjan.quiz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.example.gulmarjan.quiz, PID: 1648
>                                                                             java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:354)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:489)
>                                                                                 at com.example.gulmarjan.quiz.MainActivity3$1.onClick(MainActivity3.java:54)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: you must check 'str!=null' before use `str`.

Comment: Or, more better, ask yourself why `str` is null in this case, and if this is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't convert the empty or null string into integer as it will throw an exception.

```
  bool hasScore= intent.hasExtra("score2");

  if(hasScore){

      score3 = getIntent().getStringExtra("score2") + "";
      if(!score3.isEmpty()){
         score3=Integer.valueOf(str);
         score3++;
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must convert your String to an integer and check if getIntent() is not null as below;

```
        Intent intent=getIntent();
           if (intent != null){
               String str = intent.getStringExtra("score2");
               score3=Integer.parseInt(str);
               score3++;
           }
```